# Simple image/div slider that is ie9 friendly?

Tags: java, jquery, html, css

What is the simplest content slider that I can use that will work with IE9?

Comment: Would prefer without plugins also! :) but will try them all out

Answer (score 4):

Heres is a few good ones to get started.

http://cssslider.com/

http://liquidslider.com/

http://docs.dev7studios.com/jquery-plugins/nivo-slider